# duplicate all column in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, awk

I am trying to duplicate all the columns in my file. My file is very large consisting of 600,000 columns and 300 rows - tab separated. Here I am just showing a small part of my file on which I am trying to work.

```
rs      71_1203 71_1299 71_6634
40896   3       3       4
70786   2       2       4
116950  2       2       4
5891    3       3       4
6254    3       2       4
89308   2       2       4
116953  2       2       4
116956  2       2       4
20709   3       2       4
12524   2       2       4
12603   2       2       4
21074   2       2       1
42672   2       2       4
40972   2       2       4
21727   3       2       4
22163   2       2       4
22417   2       2       4
41216   2       2       4
41374   2       2       4
```

now I want my file to look like this:

```
rs      rs      71_1203 71_1203 71_1299 71_1299 71_6634 71_6634
40896   40896   3       3       3       3       4       4
70786   70786   2       2       2       2       4       4
116950  116950  2       2       2       2       4       4
5891    5891    3       3       3       3       4       4
6254    6254    3       3       2       2       4       4
89308   89308   2       2       2       2       4       4
116953  116953  2       2       2       2       4       4
116956  116956  2       2       2       2       4       4
20709   20709   3       3       2       2       4       4
12524   12524   2       2       2       2       4       4
12603   12603   2       2       2       2       4       4
21074   21074   2       2       2       2       1       1
42672   42672   2       2       2       2       4       4
40972   40972   2       2       2       2       4       4
21727   21727   3       3       2       2       4       4
22163   22163   2       2       2       2       4       4
22417   22417   2       2       2       2       4       4
41216   41216   2       2       2       2       4       4
41374   41374   2       2       2       2       4       4
```

All columns duplicated. 
I did this using awk command -

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$1 = $1 OFS $1} 1' try.txt | 
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$3 = $3 OFS $3} 1' |
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$5 = $5 OFS $5} 1' | 
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$7 = $7 OFS $7} 1'
```

I know this command is good when we small file but I with my file having 600,000 columns this way will not work for sure.

Can someone help me as to how can I do this is an easy way?

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: You have python-2.7 tagged here.  Are you looking for a python solution to replace awk?

Comment: I am trying with python also, so only I have tagged it.

Comment: What is the purpose of duplicating them?  Perhaps this is an X-Y problem?

Comment: this is the file format required for a diploid organism.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Perl one-liner

```
 perl -lpe 's/$/\t/g; s/(\S+\s*)/$1$1/g '  input_file
```

with the given inputs

```
$ cat rhkss.txt
rs      71_1203 71_1299 71_6634
40896   3       3       4
70786   2       2       4
116950  2       2       4
5891    3       3       4
6254    3       2       4
89308   2       2       4
116953  2       2       4
116956  2       2       4
20709   3       2       4
12524   2       2       4
12603   2       2       4
21074   2       2       1
42672   2       2       4
40972   2       2       4
21727   3       2       4
22163   2       2       4
22417   2       2       4
41216   2       2       4
41374   2       2       4

$ perl -lpe 's/$/\t/g; s/(\S+\s*)/$1$1/g ' rhkss.txt
rs      rs      71_1203 71_1203 71_1299 71_1299 71_6634 71_6634
40896   40896   3       3       3       3       4       4
70786   70786   2       2       2       2       4       4
116950  116950  2       2       2       2       4       4
5891    5891    3       3       3       3       4       4
6254    6254    3       3       2       2       4       4
89308   89308   2       2       2       2       4       4
116953  116953  2       2       2       2       4       4
116956  116956  2       2       2       2       4       4
20709   20709   3       3       2       2       4       4
12524   12524   2       2       2       2       4       4
12603   12603   2       2       2       2       4       4
21074   21074   2       2       2       2       1       1
42672   42672   2       2       2       2       4       4
40972   40972   2       2       2       2       4       4
21727   21727   3       3       2       2       4       4
22163   22163   2       2       2       2       4       4
22417   22417   2       2       2       2       4       4
41216   41216   2       2       2       2       4       4
41374   41374   2       2       2       2       4       4

$
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk` fo duplicate all the columns separated by a tab:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {
     for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i OFS, $i (i < NF ? OFS : RS)}' file
```

```
rs  rs  71_1203 71_1203 71_1299 71_1299 71_6634 71_6634
40896   40896   3   3   3   3   4   4
70786   70786   2   2   2   2   4   4
116950  116950  2   2   2   2   4   4
5891    5891    3   3   3   3   4   4
6254    6254    3   3   2   2   4   4
89308   89308   2   2   2   2   4   4
116953  116953  2   2   2   2   4   4
116956  116956  2   2   2   2   4   4
20709   20709   3   3   2   2   4   4
12524   12524   2   2   2   2   4   4
12603   12603   2   2   2   2   4   4
21074   21074   2   2   2   2   1   1
42672   42672   2   2   2   2   4   4
40972   40972   2   2   2   2   4   4
21727   21727   3   3   2   2   4   4
22163   22163   2   2   2   2   4   4
22417   22417   2   2   2   2   4   4
41216   41216   2   2   2   2   4   4
41374   41374   2   2   2   2   4   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" '{
    for(i=NF*2;i>1;i--)                                        # from NF*2 down to 2
        $i=((j=i/2)==int(j)?$j:$(++j))                         # $i=$(ceil(1/2))
}1' file
```

Output:

```
rs      rs      71_1203 71_1203 71_1299 71_1299 71_6634 71_6634
40896   40896   3       3       3       3       4       4
70786   70786   2       2       2       2       4       4
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Python approach:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    text = f.readlines()
    duplicated_text = ['\t'.join([word + '\t' + word for word in line.split('\t')]) for line in text]

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(duplicated_text))
```